# Retrofit 2 async call return response

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, httprequest, retrofit

i'm doing an android App with Retrofit, the problem i have is i need to return the response.body() from the Callback, this is my code:

```
public class RoundListProvider {
    //Load Rounds
    private static RoundsInterface roundClient = RetroBuilder.createService(RoundsInterface.class);
    private static RoundList mRoundList;
    public static RoundList getRoundList(final Context mContext)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "We're in",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Fetch info from rounds
        Call<RoundList> call = roundClient.getRounds();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RoundList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<RoundList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                Log.d("BODY", response.body().toString());
                Log.d("MESSAGE", response.message());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Conexión al servidor hecha con exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mRoundList = response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("BODY", t.getMessage());
                Log.d("ERRRO", t.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        });
        return mRoundList;
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, the return mRoundList is always null, because never waits for response to be done, can someone help me with this?.

Comment: help you with what exactly ?

Comment: If you need the entire response body, why you don't use OKHttp then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix synchronous method calls and asynchronous callbacks like that - once you enter `Callback`-land you have to stay there.

The code that calls `getRoundList()` (presumably in some `Activity` or `Fragment`) then *does something with* the returned value, right? Instead of just storing the body to `mRoundList` in the `onResponse` - do what you want to happen with the value there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is i needed to use the response data in a Recycler View, so i did this, maybe not the best, but it works. In my provider i added a new function:

```
public static void savedRoundList(RoundList roundList, Activity activity, Context context)
{
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.rvRounds);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    List<RoundData> roundData = roundList.getRounds();
    RoundAdapter adapter = new RoundAdapter(roundData);
    Log.d("RESPONSE & ERROR", roundList.getStatus()+ " "+ roundList.getCode());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So, in the Callback i just us the function savedRoundList:

```
savedRoundList(response.body(), mActivity, mContext);
```

And voilà, it works.